# place figure in this format in latex

Tags: floats

[image]how to place figure in this format??

```
a                          - a

 b                          - b

 c                          - c

 figure1Name               -  figure2Name
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It's not clear from what you've written what it is that you are asking...

Comment: It is also not clear what is meant by 'figure'. Is this an image file (PDF, PNG etc.)? Then just use `\includegraphics`.

Comment: @karishma, as an example, how should looks a MWE, see both answer below. Your MWE (in question) should contain a code resulting from your effort to  find solution. With it the question is more clear, what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using `minipage`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}\\
            a.
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-a}\\
            a.
        \end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}\\
            b.
        \end{minipage}\hfill
        \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-b}\\
            b.
        \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}\\
                c.
            \end{minipage}\hfill
            \begin{minipage}{0.45\textwidth}
                \centering
                \includegraphics[height=3cm]{example-image-c}\\
                c.
            \end{minipage}
        \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And you have this:

[image: Test]

Comment: yes ..I tries this format.. all are .jpg image.. I need format as - all figure one below the other with name as a, b, c on left hand side and same a, b, c, on right hand side . Next complete figure name below on left side and same on right hand side

Comment: It's kind of hard to imagine what you mean. Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have edited the question..

Comment: I have edited my answer. Is this what you looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution with use of `subfloat` environments from package `subfig` grouped in `minipage`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}% for showing page layout only, in real use it had to be removed

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
\caption{my first figure}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-a}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-b}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image-c}}
\caption{my second figure}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Beside `subfloat` you also can use `subfigure` from package `subcaption`. It is more powerful but require a slightly more code, for example:

```
\begin{subfigure}[t]{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{example-image}
\end{subfigure}
```

In both case you can accommodate sub captions to your taste. Above is used default preset. For details see documentations for these packages and also of package `caption`.